# Creating new columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a column that specifies the type os sanctions used in my data. This is what it looks like:

```
                          country  sanction_type
                        (chr)           (int)
1                           China         2
2                         Austria         5
3                    South Africa         1
4                          Poland         6
5                          Poland         7
6 Bolivia, Plurinational State of         2
```

The types of sanctions range from 1-10. How can I create two extra columns, one including sanction types 1,2,3,4 and the other one 5,6,7,8,9,10. I would also like to keep the exisiting one with all sanctions types. Many thanks!

The dataset has more than 6 observations, this is just a sample of the data. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Do you want the extra columns to be dummy variables?

Comment: Yes i'd like them to be dummies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dplyr package:

```
country <- c("China","Austria","South Africa","Poland", "Poland", "Bolivia")
sanction_type <- c(2,5,1,6,7,2)
df <- data.frame(country, sanction_type)

library(dplyr)

df <- mutate(df, srange1 = ifelse(sanction_type <= 4, 1, 0),
             srange2 = ifelse(sanction_type >= 5, 1, 0))
```

Comment: There is really no need to load a package just to add a column.  Plenty of ways to do it in base R.  If you like `mutate`, base R's `transform` is functionally the same.

Comment: I just realised i didn't make clear that i have more observations in the actual data, 1097 to be extact. So i'm looking for a way to divide the sanctions types into two separate columns (1,2,3,4 & 5,6,7,8,9,10)

Comment: @jo.magi That is what the code does. Just replace df by the name of your dataframe. The part before library(dplyr) is just for purpose of illustration.

Comment: @udden2903 - I totally agree.  *dplyr* is a great package with many benefits.  This particular operation, however, is very basic and really doesn't require any more functionality than base R provides us with.  But don't let my opinion deter you, as I am just one of many.

Answer (score 4):

Let your data frame be `dat`,

```
dat$less4 <- as.integer(dat$sanction_type <= 4L)
dat$great5 <- 1L - dat$less4
```

I saw that your `sanction_type` column has integer type, so I am doing integer operation all the time, to get integer result.